# WordPress data export questions

Tags: wordpress

I have very limited with experience with WordPress. I am tasked with migrating WP data from a WP V 3.6 to a new database. I exported one of the sections as XML through WP export. I have two questions about the exported XML.

1. There are three date fields associated with that section. Post Date, Event Date and end Date.
   Post Date shows up as

```
               "post_date": {
                  "__text": "2019-08-12 17:54:08"
               }
```

Event date and end date appears under postmeta as

```
                  {
                     "meta_key": {
                        "__text": "event_date_end"
                     },
                     "meta_value": {
                        "__cdata": "1568395800"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "meta_key": {
                        "__text": "event_date"
                     },
                     "meta_value": {
                        "__cdata": "1568392200"
                     }
                  },
```

what format is used here and how can I convert it to a Date format?

2. This particular section (table) has associations with two other sections (venues, artists) but I can't seem to find these associations in the XML file. Am I missing something there?

Any help is appreciated
[image]

Comment: The answer to the first question is that's a UNIX timestamp. Use PHPs DateTime to convert. For #2, we would have no idea since we don't have access to your site. HOW are those other sections associated?

Comment: thank you! Its hard for me to describe how those sections are associated since I did not make  them and this is the first time I am dealing with WP. I added a screen shot of what that page looks like to my original post. If that can shed a light on it great otherwise I understand that it is difficult to tell what is going on with certainty

Comment: Look under Plugins. Is this the Tribe Events plugin?

Comment: there is not. I can add a venue by clicking on the venue on the left menu and then go to event and associate it with an event

Comment: Without seeing the actual code, probably won't be able to help much. Are you moving the site to a newer version of WordPress?

Comment: no. they are found a different solution and are in the process of migrating their existing data now

Comment: Ahh....good luck! You may need to write a custom database query to get what you want.